# Python pyramid with letter

Tags: python

My problem is that I have to make a pyramid of letters in the middle of the screen. The output has to be a pyramid of 15 levels. This assignment has to be done with definition. The output should be like

```
              a
             aba
            abcba 
           abcdcba 
          abcdedcba 
         abcdefedbca 
        abcdefgfedcba
       abcdefghgfedcba 
      abcdefghihgfedcba
     abcdefghijihgfedcba 
    abcdefghijkjihgfedcba 
   abcdefghijklkjihgfedcba 
  abcdefghijklmlkjihgfedcba
 abcdefghijklmnmlkjihgfedcba 
abcdefghijklmnonmlkjihgfedcba
```

I have already produced some code but it is not working. Can anybody please help me?

```
def print_a_to_y():
    palindrome=""
    for i in range (ord('a'),ord('z')):
        palindrome = palindrome+ chr(i)
    return palindrome


def print_y_to_a():
    palindrome=""
    for i in range (ord('z'),ord('a')-1, -1):
        palindrome += chr(i)
    return palindrome


def palin ():
    paal = print_a_to_y() + 'z' + print_y_to_a() 
    print paal

def pyramid (levels=15):
    for i in range (levels):
        print palin (levels-i-1) + palin (2*i+1)

pyramid()
```

Comment: What exactly is not working? Provide some description

Comment: Just for fun a one-liner: `print('\n'.join('{0:.>{2}}{1:.<{2}}'.format(string.ascii_lowercase[:current_line],(string.ascii_lowercase[::-1] + ' ')[-current_line:], levels) for current_line in range(1, levels + 1)))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tolen,
you have several minor mistakes and one logical issue in the function

```
print_y_to_a()
```

Be aware that this function produces a string that begins with z, but you want to concatenate your string in reverse direction where your other function print_a_to_y() did stop (+1 position). For example:

```
abc -> comes from print_a_to_y()
ba  -> should come from print_y_to_a().
```

Also be aware that you need to add the new line character "\n" to achieve some nice output.

Here is my solution:

```
def print_a_to_y(lev):
    palindrome = ""
    counter = 0
    for i in range(ord('a'), ord('z')):
        if counter <= lev:
            palindrome = palindrome + chr(i)
            counter += 1
        else:
            pass
    return palindrome


def print_y_to_a(cut):
    palindrome = ""
    for i in range(ord('z'), ord('a') - 1, -1):
        palindrome = palindrome + chr(i)
    return palindrome[-cut:]


def palin(lev):
    paal = print_a_to_y(lev) + print_y_to_a(lev)
    return paal


def pyramid(levels=15):
    res = ""
    for i in range(levels):
        if i == 0:
            res = print_a_to_y(i) + "\n"
        elif i > 0:
            res = res + str(palin(i)) + "\n"
        else:
            pass
    return res


print(pyramid())
```

Also you need the return statement at the end of a function, otherwise 'None' will be on your screen.

Cheers, hope this helps.
Viktor

Comment: Hi, Tolen. Don't forget to Up Vote if the answer where what you wanted. Thx, Bye.

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
levels = 15


def pyramid(levels=15):
    lines = []
    i = (levels - 1)
    while i >= 0:
        temp = ((" " * i) + alphabet[:levels - i])
        left = temp
        right = temp[::-1][1:]
        line = (left + right)
        lines.append(line)
        i -= 1
    return "\r\n".join(lines)


def upside_down_pyramid(levels=15):
    lines = []
    i = 0
    while i < levels:
        temp = ((" " * i) + alphabet[:levels - i])
        left = temp
        right = temp[::-1][1:]
        line = (left + right)
        lines.append(line)
        i += 1
    return "\r\n".join(lines)


print(pyramid(levels))
print(upside_down_pyramid(levels))
```

Result:

```
              a              
             aba             
            abcba            
           abcdcba           
          abcdedcba          
         abcdefedcba         
        abcdefgfedcba        
       abcdefghgfedcba       
      abcdefghihgfedcba      
     abcdefghijihgfedcba     
    abcdefghijkjihgfedcba    
   abcdefghijklkjihgfedcba   
  abcdefghijklmlkjihgfedcba  
 abcdefghijklmnmlkjihgfedcba 
abcdefghijklmnonmlkjihgfedcba
abcdefghijklmnonmlkjihgfedcba
 abcdefghijklmnmlkjihgfedcba 
  abcdefghijklmlkjihgfedcba  
   abcdefghijklkjihgfedcba   
    abcdefghijkjihgfedcba    
     abcdefghijihgfedcba     
      abcdefghihgfedcba      
       abcdefghgfedcba       
        abcdefgfedcba        
         abcdefedcba         
          abcdedcba          
           abcdcba           
            abcba            
             aba             
              a
```